# Computing diagonal sums in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a fairly large rectangular numpy array, of shape `(m, n)`, for example:

```py
>>> a.shape
(27584, 34092)
```

I have to compute the sum of each [anti-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) of the array. This new array will have a shape of `(m + n - 1,)`.

The simplistic approach is to do:

```py
m, n = a.shape
r = np.zeros(m + n - 1)
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        r[i + j] += a[i][j]

# r is the sum of all anti-diagonals of a
```

This is obviously very slow, is there any way to perform the calculation using a clever numpy primitive? My only other option would be to code this in C++, which is also doable too - but requires more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the most intuitive solution is to:

- use *a[::-1]* to "flip" the order of rows, so that then you can
  operate on "normal" diagonals,
- use *np.diagonal* to access each diagonal,
- sum the returned diagonal,
- put the above code in a list comprehension.

So the whole code can be:

```
result = [np.diagonal(a[::-1], offs).sum() for offs in range(-a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[1])]
```

It should run significantly faster than your code.

Since your source array is quite a big one, maybe you will get some speed
gain by:

- computing the "flipped" array **once**, at the beginning,
- then operate on this array:

So the reworked code, including a hint about *np.trace* (see comments),
can be:

```
b = a[::-1]
result = [np.trace(b, offs) for offs in range(-a.shape[0] + 1, a.shape[1])]
```

Comment: You can use `np.trace()` as a shortcut for `np.diagonal(...).sum()`.

Comment: I ended up redoing it in C++ to ensure it's fast for larger matrices and the code is not too complex. However, this solution is quite good anyway so I accepted it. @Valdi_bo